# i want to convert string and integer to unsigned byte

Tags: java, memory

In java 
i have two variables

```
String string;
int integerValue;
```

I want to convert these values to unsignedbyte
that is 
How to convert string to UnsignedByte
and
integer  to UnsignedByte

Comment: Which UnsignedByte would that be? The Axis one? If you could add the package name that would be great. It would also be good if you could elaborate on what you want to achieve, because there are possibly alternative methods or best practices for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not have an unsigned byte.

Converting from String to `short` is done by `Short.parseShort(string)`

If you are referring to Axis's `UnsignedByte` class, you can use the constructors:

```
new UnsignedByte(sting);
new UnsignedByte(integerValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have type like unsigned byte, you have to use larger short for this (for unsigned int it has to be long).

```
short s = (short) integerValue;
```